# Setting buad rate gives "unable to perform all requested operations"

Tags: stty

I am on Ubuntu Mate and I am trying to set the baud rate for tty7. stty gives "unable to perform all requested operations". Any help?

Comment: I found a script to test all speeds. The script gives "unable to perform". Here's the script  #!/bin/sh

for bauds in $(
    sed -r 's/^#define\s+B([1-9][0-9]+)\s+.*/\1/p;d' < \
        /usr/include/asm-generic/termbits.h ) ;do
    echo $bauds
    stty -F /dev/tty7 $bauds && echo Ok.
done  2>&1 |
    pr -at2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to set baud rate of the virtual terminal in this way. Since the `/dev/ttyNUMBER` devices are not real serial ports, it is not possible.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197340/setting-custom-baud-rate-on-console/381521#381521) for details.